# java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: subject key, Could not create EC public key

Tags: java, eclipse, security, file-io

**hi, I got this error when executing my program. I am trying to read a certificate from a Keystrore and i got the following error:**

```
java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: subject key, Could not create EC public key
at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:171)
at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1781)
at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:196)
at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:97)
at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:747)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
......
```

**This is the code i used to read the certificate:**

```
public static Certificate getCerticate(String KSpwd, String KSname, String alias) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException{

    //Before a keystore can be accessed, it must be loaded.
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        // get user password and file input stream
        char[] password = KSpwd.toCharArray();
        java.io.FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(KSname);
        ks.load(fis, password);
        fis.close();


    //Get the certificate from the Key Store
        Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(alias);

        return cert;
}
```

Comment: i have debug it and have seen that is the instruction ks.load() that is generating the error, please help!!!!

Comment: Could you please show your entire code ? it seems the problem is not with the keystore loading part.

Comment: Thanks i've seen the problem, i had to comment the NSS provider in the java.security file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to comment out the NSS provider in the `java.security` file and everything will be working fine then.